# Testing for Mean Differences for Two Discrete Random Variables

Tags: random-variables, means, discrete-calculus

Two discrete random variables come from two different distributions. If you know the mean and variance of each discrete distribution, is there a test to show that the two means are statistically the same? If yes, what would this test be?

Comment: What do you mean by "means that are statistically the same"? Btw, if you know the means then it is clear immediately that they are the same or not.

Comment: Have a look at the t-test

Comment: Well, we would like to know if the two means are not significantly different from each other. Would the t-test work in a discrete case, too?